# My knee keeps buckling when I am in horse stance or preparing for kicks

Tags: karate, stance

I am 17 and I do Karate. My knee keeps buckling whenever I am in horse stance, or doing a front thrust kick. It is almost like it's going backwards. My instructors ask us to go as low and wide as we can in our stance. They want me to exaggerate distance. We do single, triple and punches in threes while in horse stance, and that is when it usually buckles. My feet are always pointed forward, I try not to lean. We do this for a good minute, maybe a little less. I am 90% sure that weight is distributed correctly. I started stretching every other day and running backwards as well doing wall squats, also just stretching more before practicing at the dojo.

Should I wrap my knee and wear a knee brace while I do karate?

Comment: Please see a medical professional about your knee problem - random internet people don't usually make the best doctors.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You could salvage the question by refocusing it on how to improve your horse stance. This should be on topic. However, medical advise is indeed off topic.

Comment: Hi Catherine - there can be many reasons why this is happening, can you explain further? How deep in horse stance are you? Feet straight or angled out? How long are you in position before your knee buckles? Are you large or small? When moving or standing in your stance is your weight correctly distributed? Have you done any strength work?

Comment: my instructors ask us to go as low and wide as we can in our stance they want me to exaggerate distance, we do single, triple and punches in three while in horse stance, that when it usual it buckles. My feet are always pointed forward, I try not lean,  we do this for a good minute maybe a little less. I am 90% sure that weight is distributed correctly. I started stretching every other day and running backwards as well doing wall squats, also just stretching more before practicing at the dojo.

Comment: I see this from time to time in some students, so I do think it relevant to martial arts.  Kindly reword it, and indicate what your doctor says, if you've seen a doctor.  I'm curious if you suffer from a condition called "genu recurvatum" (aka, knee hyperextension or back knee).  In this case, you will definitely need to see a specialist who can help you work with your instructor.  Otherwise, simple strength exercises - barring any abnormality your doctor might indicate - might be in order for you.

Comment: That's great detail Catherine - can you edit that into your question (hit the edit link below the question), then we can get your question re-opened.

Comment: I don't understand whether there are any special knee considerations in this question. Are your knees normal and you just need advice on how to have a stable horse stance?

Comment: I also do not understand what "My knee keeps buckling whenever I am in horse stance front thus kick it is almost like it's going backwards" means. In your additional comment, you are punching when your knee buckles. What does kicking have to do with this? What's going backwards?

Comment: When you say your instructors want your stance low and wide, how wide is this? Are your feet underneath your knees, or are your feet our wider than your knees?

Comment: My suspicion is that that line should be "My knee keeps buckling whenever I am in horse stance or doing a front thrust kick; it is almost like it's going backwards", but I'm hesitant to edit it to that because it requires some assumption of intent.

Comment: I overcame my wariness of assuming intent here. I'm still not certain of the correct answer because I don't necessarily follow how the knee could buckle backwards in a situation where it's bent the other direction.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - genu recurvatum is a condition of the knee bending backward.  Not backward like a bird's knee, but that it extends further back than normal, giving the appearance that it's buckling.  It's commonly called back knee.

Here's an example: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/dd/5b/ed/dd5bed64a5ca18e2cf759a348ec2ab8f.jpg

Comment: It is not really clear how a buckling (back) knee can occur in a horse stance, so I'm waiting for question clarification to get better idea.

Comment: The other possibility is that it's not so much "bending backwards" as "becoming unstable while bent" in a way that feels a bit like a the knee shifting back. I've had that experience once or twice, albeit only in passing and not consistently. If it is that case, I suspect that better exercise/condition will help stabilize the knee, as fatigue was always a factor for me.

Comment: Why did we reopen this question? This may not be a medical question, but does anyone understand what is being asked?

Comment: The author was actively participating in improving the question at the time.

Comment: Late to the party, but if the horse stance is ok, and buckles on the punches, I would suspect that the user is letting their feet rotate with the hip shifts instead of remaining in place (Perhaps in an attempt to put too much power into the punch). Horse stance is a very poor stance to throw powerful, effective punches from. (In fact, other than training or forms, I can't think of any situation where I would even want to *be* in horse stance.